# How to configure protractor to work with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, protractor

For karma it's as simple as adding this line to the config file:

`frameworks: ['requirejs','mocha']`

According to the [grunt-protractor-runner docs](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner#optionsargs), there is a `framework` option available but it says `Limited support for using mocha as the test framework instead of jasmine`  and nothing about requirejs (or any other framework for that matter).

At the moment if I try to run my tests I'm getting:

`ReferenceError: define is not defined`

How do I get protractor to play with requirejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, protractor is server-side testing therefore it doesn't need any of the front end frameworks to work.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Even if you realized you don't need it, other might.

Comment: thanks for the update, I edited the answer accordingly